# Why factory won't Work? (Angular.js)

Tags: angularjs, render, factory

If i pass the factory name inside my controller parameter, the function inside it seems not work, also in the view i see the render of brackets....
What i am doing wrong?

HERE WHAT I SEE:
[image]

instead, If i don't pass the service inside the controller, it seems to work
**JS**

```
var LandingApp = angular.module('LandingApp',[]);

LandingApp.factory('PreventivoTotaleFront',function(){

var voci = {};
voci.lista = [];

AggiungiVoce.add = function(voce){
    voci.lista.push({
        id: voci.lista.length,
        costo: voce
    })  
};

return voci; 
});

 //CONTROLLER 
LandingApp.controller('numberpages',function($scope,PreventivoTotaleFront){

$scope.primapagina = 150;
$scope.altrepagine = 90;
$scope.numeroaltrepagine = 0;

$scope.TotaleEuroPagine = 0;

$scope.CalcolaTotaleEuroPagine = function(){
    return $scope.TotaleEuroPagine = $scope.altrepagine * $scope.numeroaltrepagine + $scope.primapagina;
    AggiungiVoce.add(TotaleEuroPagine);
    alert(TotaleEuroPagine);
};

 });
```

**The HTML**

```
    <body ng-app="LandingApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="numberpages">

        <form>

            <label>N° Pagine interne: </label><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="numeroaltrepagine" ng-change="CalcolaTotaleEuroPagine()"></input>
            <br/>{{TotaleEuroPagine | currency:""}}€<br/>

        </form>
        <br/><br/>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="VociPreventivo in lista.voci">{{voci.id}} : {{voci.costo}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your variable AggiungiVoce is not pre-defined. This will result in undesirable behavior(i.e. it'll get created as a global). If my translation of it is correct(Add Item), then it should be a method anyway. You should add it and other methods to an object and return that. That way, all those methods will be available anywhere you inject the factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using factory properly. You need to return a object containing methods.

```
var LandingApp = angular.module('LandingApp', []);
LandingApp.factory('PreventivoTotaleFront', function () {
    var voci = {};
    voci.lista = [];

    return {
        add: function (voce) {
            voci.lista.push({
                id: voci.lista.length,
                costo: voce
            })
        }
    };
});
```

As use factory in the controller i.e. `PreventivoTotaleFront.add()`

```
//CONTROLLER
LandingApp.controller('numberpages', function ($scope, PreventivoTotaleFront) {
    $scope.CalcolaTotaleEuroPagine = function () {
        PreventivoTotaleFront.add(TotaleEuroPagine);        
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your factory PreventivoTotaleFront, you return voci object if you put your function add inside this returning object like

```
voci: {
  add: function() {}
}
```

and then you can call it from your controller like

```
PreventivoTotaleFront.add()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating your AggiungiVoce variable(with `var`) before you use it(in `AggiungiVoce.add`). In such a case, JavaScript looks in parent scope for the existence of that variable AggiungiVoce all the way up to global scope. There it's assigned. So that is why you're able to use it when the factory is not injected.

In the factory, you should create an object of methods and return that. Since factories are only created once, you are able to access those methods anywhere you inject the factory.